# iPhone app: "Parse issue - expected ';' after @synthesize"

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm working on an iPhone app and got this strange things happening.

I have a property declared in my .h file:

```
BOOL shouldProcessVenueListRequest;
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL shouldProcessVenueListRequest;
```

So far, so good.  Then in my implementation .m file:

```
@synthesize shouldProcessVenueListRequest;
```

This works perfectly well for about 20 other properties, but for this one, I'm getting an error in the implementation: "Parse Issue - Expected ';' after @synthesize" - and the error pointer is in the middle of the variable name - see the image.

[image]

I tried removing and re-adding this property manually; tried copy/paste variable name from .h - nothing worked.  I'm totally confused about this now.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try searching out the code. You must have missed putting ; (semicolon) at some place.

Comment: That's very weird, But if it was a non-printable character as @AliSoftware suggested, you would get an error saying something like "stray '/XXX' in program" where XXX is (ASCII I guess) code of the character which gives you problems. I suppose you have tried Product -> Clean?

Comment: What will be if you'll write in such way: `@synthesize shouldSaveSearchDetails, shouldProcessVenueListRequest;`?

Comment: @Aleks G: Can you show all the synthesize statements??

Comment: This can happen if you have circular import statements, e.g. Class A imports B, and Class B imports A. Consider using the @class keyword to help you.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the comment.  Please read the accepted answer.  There was nothing wrong with the code, just a bug with XCode.

Comment: @AleksG I did read that - but I thought it might help someone else (like my past self(!)) who had this problem to know of other causes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to all who replied. It turned out to be an issue with the XCode rather than anything wrong with my code.  Apparently, when I was typing the code in, I was interrupted half-way into typing, so that error message was valid (at the time).  Then, about an hour later I came back to it and completed typing - but for some reason XCode was stuck on this error message.

I did 'clean', then 'build' - didn't help.  So I did 'clean' again and then closed project.  When I reopened the project and did 'build' again - the error wasn't there any more.

Comment: I had a very similar issue except I got that error next an IBAction. I closed out of Xcode and did "clean" and the errors went away. Frustrating that it was Xcode's mistake and not in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Strange problem. Try the following:

- Try another name for your property (maybe it is a keyword/name used elsewhere, namely in any of Apple's framwork or similar - you could try command-clic on the word to see if Xcode finds its definition anywhere else than in your header file maybe?)
- Be sure there is no hidden (non-printable) character
- Try another place for your `@synthesize`, moving it one or two lines below, to check if the error comes from this very property or the one above it

---

***[EDIT]** Did't see this in your screenshot the first time, but it seems you have a semicolon right in the middle of your `@synthesize shouldProcessVenueListRequ;est;`, between the 'qu' and the 'est'... or is it the Fix-it proposition?*

Comment: This is the Fix-it proposition.  Naturally, I didn't have it there :)

Comment: OK so maybe this is a hint that it suggests the semicolon at this very location, maybe a non-printable character around? Did you try my other suggestions? Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Check your code to ensure a few things

1. There is no space between **shouldProcessVenueListRequ** and **est** (even I thought you had a ; in there between the two parts :)
2. If you are copy-pasting the variable name from some place, you might want to type it all out manually (as Ali suggests, there might be a hidden character)
3. Try doing a clean-build

Answer (score 0):

Even I got the same problem. When I checked it out, I gave the same name for variables but in different files. I just gave different names for all the variables, like if I have used a variable coupon in more than one file, I made it one as couponDisplay in one and couponList as another.